# C++ MoveFile error (2) on windows 7

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

I have a small app which try to move files.

Here is the min code:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    MoveFile("C:\\test.txt", "C:\\folder\\test.txt");
    // Here I use GetLastError() to get last error code witch is 2 and I can't find what mean;

    return 0;
}
```

IMPORTANT: This error appear on windows 7 but on win XP works, the file is moved!

Comment: My guess `C:\folder` does not exist or `C:\test.txt` does not exist. On Windows 7 you'd need admin rights to actually write to `C:\` so just because you see a `test.txt` in Explorer doesn't mean it is actually in that location. But I don't know whether `MoveFile` is aware of this per-user virtual store mechanism ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find all the error codes [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or in your header files.

2 is `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` which means your source file couldn't be found when you were trying this on Windows 7. Make sure you had the correct relative/absolute path in there.

Comment: Ops, I was having the wrong path. Okay now I just recive error code 5 which means "ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED". The file I try to move is not in use by other process.

Comment: Windows 7 has different privileges for admin users. Check your UAC. Do some research on your own.

Comment: @daffr32: read my comment at your question. Of course you'd receive `5`, because on Windows 7 (and Vista) rules have changed, compared with XP. Either run the program as admin, or simply use a location to test your program which is not affected by permission issues, such as `%USERPROFILE%\Desktop` ...

Comment: Ok, now I just run it as Administrator and file was moved. But I was loged already with administrator privileges, why I was having to do right click run as..? Is it posible to move file without this action if user is loged as admin?

Comment: Have you used a PC since Windows Vista came out? Read up on UAC.

Comment: In fact that's my first personal use of win newer than xp sp3. I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your example has a typo. You are missing a backslash on you destination filename. Windows will typically generate error 2 in this circumstance